# How to Change the height of UIPageControl?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uipagecontrol

I am trying to change the height of `UIPageControl` how I can achieve that?

Comment: Yes set the frame for it..                                     'pageControl.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not using interface builder, but you can specify a new frame in code:

```
pageControl.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
```

Answer (score 3):

Agree With Mike

You can change your UIPageControl height using its frame..

ex

```
 pgControl.frame = CGRectMake(X , Y , Width , Height that you want);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how you do that

Change the width to something strange, 153

Now open the xib as source.

Find 153

Nearby you should see number 36. Change that to the height you want.

Tada...... :)

Comment: Thank you! My page control was 291 px high and I could not change it in the storyboard. Changing it in the source code fixed it and also helped me fixing the constraint warnings I had when running the application. Brilliant idea searching for the strange numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Drag UIView in your XIB, then change Its class to UIPageControl

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, but wanted to solve it in storyboard. Just drop a new View to your windows main view. Then drag the UIPageControl item to the new View. Now you can adjust the height of the new view as desired. The contained UIPageControl is clipped accordingly. Most properly you have to adjust the position of the UIPageControl inside the new view to get a proper display. Don't forget to set "Clip Subviews" for the new view.

Answer (score 0):

have you done tried like this?

```
UIPageControl *pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width/2,  self.frame.size.height -20, (self.frame.size.width/nimages)/2, 20)];  
pageControl.numberOfPages=nimages;  
[pageControl setNeedsLayout];  
[self addSubview:pageControl];
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, a little different code.  It updates the view's frame property of your page control.  I put this in the viewDidLoad method of my PageViewController.m file

```
self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

**For swift 4.2:**

```
pageControl.frame = CGRect(x: desired x, y: desired y, width:  desired width, height:  desired height);
```

Answer (score -1):

if you using interface builder, you can add new constrants for your UIPageControl.Like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jt0L.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5bMt.png)

i add a beautiful background color to make you see clearly.